# chrome extension: getting user's email address who logs into the google account/gmail account

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have built a chrome extension. Using chrome.identity.getAuth(), I am able to get token as described here https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_identity. This token seems to be for the user who is associated with the chrome.

I want to get a token or a user's email address who logs into the google account/gmail account. Is it possible to get this from within an extension?

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25301018/chrome-app-getting-logged-in-users-email-address

Comment: so i can get the email of the chrome user. but i would like to get the email or some identification if the I switch a google account. for ex: login to the google calendar using a different login.

Comment: Read the question attentively, it's not about Chrome user, but the user associated with the token. More specifically, look at the answer.

Comment: that is exactly i have and i get the user's email and token for the first (or primary) user. then i switch my google account in the browser, but i still get the old email.

Comment: Please remove the google-chrome-app tag.

Comment: seems like the identity seems to be tied to the chrome account itself. if u need to switch the account, u need to switch user profile. does not work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this by choosing a web application type instead of a chrome app when generating the client id on google console.

1. Choose a web application when you are generating the client key on google

   **Javascript origins**: `https://<extensionid>.chromiumapp.org`

   **redirect url** `https://<extensionid>.chromiumapp.org/provider_cb`
2. extract the email page by reading the html from the contentscript.
3. Pass a message with this email address to the background page.
4. Follow the same as described in the github launchWebAuthFlow. [https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/github-auth]
5. When calling the google auth url, also pass `login_hint` with the email address.