# How to get Auth Token from gmail logged-in account??

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am building an extension for gmail. I need the access token to add data in spreadsheets. Chrome provides `chrome.identity.getAuthToken` for this but it returns token associated with chrome account which can be different than the gmail account user has logged in.

Comment: Did you find any workaround?

Comment: Yes, use chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow() or follow auth process for web application. I can post an answer if you'd like ?

Comment: Alright, I think you are referring to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25652040/chrome-extension-getting-users-email-address-who-logs-into-the-google-account

Comment: Yes, but I couldn't get chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow() to return refresh token(If you can,plz share how you did it). Also chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow()  prompts login screen everytime i restart chrome.So I had to use auth process like we do in web applications and extracting the token from tab url.